# Prove by induction that $b_n-a_n < (\frac {1}2)^n(b-a)$

Tags: inequality, induction, convex-optimization, means

For two numbers $a$ and $b$ with $0 \leq a\leq b $ we have that:

$a_{n+1} =\sqrt{a_nb_n} \quad$ , $\qquad b_{n+1} = \frac {a_n+b_n}2 \quad,$ $\qquad a_0 = a, \quad b_0=b $

And I have to prove for $n\ge1$ that $b_n-a_n < (\frac {1}2)^n(b-a) \quad $ if $a\neq b$

In previous exercises I've proved that:

(i) $\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{a+b}2$ $\quad$ for $\; 0\leq a \leq b \;$ with equality if and only if $a=b$

(ii) $ a <\sqrt{ab} \; $ and $\frac{a+b}2 <b \; $ for $0 \leq a<b$

By using (i) and (ii) I have done this so far:

$b_n-a_n =\frac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}2 - \sqrt{a_{n-1}b_{n-1}} $

$\qquad \quad < \frac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}2-a_{n-1}=\frac{1}2(b_{n-1}-a_{n-1}) \quad$ for $n\ge1$

I'm stuck from here.

(Edited)

Comment: You can't prove that, because it's not true. Please, check your source of that problem!

Comment: This is... incorrect. For example $a=1, b=3$, we have $a_1 = 2, b_1=\sqrt{3}$, clearly $b_1-a_1\ne\frac{1}{2}(b-a)$, since equality would imply $\sqrt{3}$ is rational.

Comment: I've corrected the informations now

Comment: You did all the work, you just need to use the induction hypothesis $b_{n-1}-a_{n-1} < (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}(b-a)$ and you're done.